# Using Material design icons instead of Font awesome with PrimeNg

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to use material design icons instead of font awesome that prime components use by default. What i need to do if i want to move to different icon library ?

Comment: I assume you're using https://materialdesignicons.com/ ? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the font-family.

```
.material-icons, .fa {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

Infact primeng has a material theme that you can cheat on.
http://www.primefaces.org/ultima-ng/ inspect icons over there and you can simply change it all icons are material in this theme.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where are you placing this?